# Negative correlation between regression residual and predicted value

Tags: multiple-regression

In multiple regression, the residual plots show a negative relation between the residual and the predicted value. What does it mean? How should I address this issue?

Here is an image, to help explain the situation. Thanks again for the help!

[image: negative correlation between regression residual and predicted value]

Comment: Could you post an example?  (If you put an image up somewhere on the Web and provide a link to it, any high-rep user can embed it in your question for all to see.)

Comment: I tried to upload the image, but I do not have enough reputation points. Any suggestion on where I can put the image on the Web for anyone to see? Thanks.

Comment: *Anywhere* you can post it publicly will work.  Try imgur.com (which is what this site uses behind the scenes).

Comment: Looks like you're fitting an entirely unsuitable model. There's one influential extreme outlier, but that's not the only issue. What are the variables in the data set measuring and what model did you fit (i.e. was it vanilla multiple regression or was there anything nonstandard about it)? A possible first step might be to try something with higher breakdown point.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is something's amiss.  By "negative relation" I assume that you are seeing what looks like negative correlation.  But, perhaps what **looks like** negative correlation is not **really** negative correlation because of (for example) overlapping points in your plot.  If you are fitting a multiple linear regression with the usual loss function (least squares), then there should be no correlation between the residuals and the predicted values.

Comment: I notice the question says negative *relation* rather than negative *correlation.*  My guess is that the O.P. has been careful here not to fall into the trap you describe. Once we can see an example we will be much better informed about the situation.  (Welcome to our site, by the way, and thanks for being an answerer as well as an asker!)

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom-left corner of the top-left plot (predicted vs residuals) you have a single large outlier. This point looks like it's distorting your fitted trend.

Interestingly, the predicted value and residual are both about -8, so the *observed* response is about 0 -- which would be in the middle of the distribution of the response.